Cómo puedo configurar un proyecto npm con licencia BSD
Corrí como siempre
npm init

pero la tratar de poner BSD en la licencia obtengo el error

Sorry, license should be a valid SPDX license expression (without "LicenseRef"), "UNLICENSED", or "SEE LICENSE IN " and license is similar to the valid expression "BSD-2-Clause".

¿Qué valor debo de poner para esta licencia BSD?

Me puse a leer la documentación de npm y las licencias las toma de https://spdx.org/licenses/
por lo que en mi caso el valor que tuve que poner fue 0BSD
